# Can't insert date from table to other with 2 condition

Tags: sql, insert

i want insert date from table to other
with 2 condition from same row
(view picture in yellow part)

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the IN in the where clause can only have one colymn, not two. You could re-write it as:

```
from emp e
inner join emp2  e2 on e.Id = e2.Id and e.storeId = e2.storeId
```

I think that this would get you the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare only one field in "not in subselect" approach.

You should give this workaround a try:

```
select .... from emp e
where not exists (
    select 1 from emp2 e2 where e.id = e2.id and e.storeid = e2.storeid 
)
```

I guess it provides exactly the same result as you need